# Vite (vite-plugin-ssr) generating separate assets build bundels under corresponding directories (per page MPA)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, vite, vite-plugin-pages

I'm building an MPA on vite react, using vite-plugin-ssr, for the purpose of html generation during development and build.
Plugin does its job greatly generating htmls, but I also need it in the dist to keep the structure of the files.

What it does now:

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ client/
|  |    index.html
|  |    ├─ assets/
|  |    |    ├─ chunks
|  |    |    ├─ enties
|  |    |    ├─ static 
|  |    ├─ about
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pageone
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pagetwo
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pagethree
|  |    |    ├─ index.html       
│  ├─ server
├─ pages/
|  |    ├─ about/
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ about.css
|  |    |    ├─ index.page.jsx
|  |    ├─ index
|  |    ├─ pageone
|  |    ├─ pagetwo
|  |    ├─ pagethree
├─ renderer
├─ server
├─ package.json
├─ vite.config.js
```

Structure in each page is the same as in the about page.

What I want it to generate:

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ client/
|  |    index.html
|  |    ├─ shared/ (keep assets for the purpose of shared files)
|  |    |    ├─ fonts
|  |    |    ├─ css
|  |    |    ├─ js
|  |    ├─ about
|  |    |    ├─ images (inside images for this page ) 
|  |    |    ├─ css (inside about.css ) 
|  |    |    ├─ js (inside about.js ) 
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pageone
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ css
|  |    |    ├─ js
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pagetwo
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ css
|  |    |    ├─ js
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pagethree
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ css
|  |    |    ├─ js
|  |    |    ├─ index.html       
│  ├─ server
├─ pages/
|  |    ├─ about/
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ about.css
|  |    |    ├─ index.page.jsx
|  |    ├─ index
|  |    ├─ pageone
|  |    ├─ pagetwo
|  |    ├─ pagethree
├─ renderer
├─ server
├─ package.json
├─ vite.config.js
```

Is it even possible? or maybe I shouldn't use the ssr plugin, but vite out of the box ssr would be more customizable for this purpose?

I have tried to do the follwing in my vite config for rollup options:

```
 build: {
    assetsDir: 'shared',
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          let extType = assetInfo.name.split('.').at(-1);
          if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
            extType = 'img';
          }
          return `slideone/${extType}/[name]-[hash][extname]`;
        },
        chunkFileNames: 'slideone/js/[name]-[hash].js',
      },
    },
  }
```

but it moved all the img css and js as a bunch into slideone (as I hardcoded it), and kept in shared folder subfolder entries.. That's the furthest I got.

```
├─ dist/
│  ├─ client/
|  |    index.html
|  |    ├─ shared/
|  |    |    ├─ enties
|  |    ├─ about
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ css (inside all css ) 
|  |    |    ├─ js (inside all js ) 
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pageone
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ css
|  |    |    ├─ js
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pagetwo
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ css
|  |    |    ├─ js
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
|  |    ├─ pagethree
|  |    |    ├─ images
|  |    |    ├─ css
|  |    |    ├─ js
|  |    |    ├─ index.html
```